# Fluentd match tag wildcard pattern matching patterns below it too?

Tags: regex, fluentd

In the Fluentd config file I have a configuration as such

`<match a.b.**.stag>`

and below it there is another match tag as follows

`<match a.b.c.d.**>`

Now as per documentation `**` will match zero or more tag parts. However I am a bit suspicious that whether the second tag will ever be matched or the event will gobbled up by first `<match>` itself. What I want to confirm is that the first tag will match the events which would have otherwise matched second event or not?
The targeted events for second `match` do NOT have `stag` in them
but rest of the things are same as the first match tag target events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I want to confirm is that the first tag will match the events which would have otherwise matched second event or not?

It really depends on the input, so: No, this is not the case in general.

```
+--------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| Tag          | Matched by a.b.**.stag | Matched by a.b.c.d.** |
+--------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
| a.b.c.stag   | X                      |                       |
| a.b.c.d.stag | X                      | X                     |
| a.b.c.d.e    |                        | X                     |
| a.b.c.stag.e |                        |                       |
+--------------+------------------------+-----------------------+
```

As a general rule though, define wide matches after tight matches.

If you need a match to rule out specific tags that should not be accepted by a following tighter match (e.g. if you don't want your second match to contain any tags with `stag`), consider using pattern lists:

`<match a.b.c.stag a.b.d.stag>`

or pattern combinations:

`<match a.b.{c,d.*}.stag>`

These are just examples since I don't know the scope of all possible tags.